# HTML / CSS Video end event issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I am currently designing a website. I have everything done but I cannot figure out this last step.

Here's the deal:

I want to play a video but I want it's z-index to be over the entire website index page. Since the video is not full screen I want the rest of the website to be black. So in a way you could say I want to have an #id that is fully black but has a video playing in the middle and this #id should be over the entire index.html page.

After the video is done playing, (maybe 5 seconds), I want it to disappear so that we are back to the index page. I do not want to change the links of my website and have it redirect me to a new page...

Can this be done? If you do not understand something please ask and I will clarify.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: use a modal dialog widget. bootstrap has one, jQuery has a million, and vanilla has https://github.com/Nycto/PicoModal

Comment: there is also CSS: video { border: 5000px solid black; z-index:999; position: relative; ... }

Comment: but how would i make the video disappear when its done playing?

Comment: does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274410/html-css-video-end-event-issue/25274611#25274611 question: when does the video begin? should the overlay be triggered by a click or something or is immediate?

Comment: <video onended="this.className+=' done'"; > ... then, in css: video.done{ border:0; z-index:1; ... }

Comment: @dandavis, I took your advice and updated the answer incase others land here. You are right =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/pbzmjkoq/7/)  - the solution below hides an overlay that is z-indexed above everything except the video. The code below uses `<video></video>`'s ended event to add a `display:none;` to the overlay.

**HTML**

```
<video id="watchMe" autoplay="true">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>       

<div id="overlay"></div>
```

**CSS**

The video's `z-index` needs to be higher than the overlay.

```
video#watchMe {
    z-index: 9999;
    position:relative;
}
```

The overlay's `z-index` needs to be higher than every element but lower than the video's.

```
#overlay {
    z-index: 9998;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
```

**Javascript**

Hide overlay when video ends

```
var video = document.getElementById('watchMe');
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

video.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    overlay.style.display = 'none'; 
}, false);
```

*Note: Versions prior to IE 9 don't play well with `addEventListener()` - [info & solutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility)*

**Jquery Alternative**

This is an option if you prefer using jQuery over raw Javascript

```
$('video').on('ended', function(){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: re: "hides an overlay element after a specificed amount of time, video length" : what if the user pauses the videop to go potty during the important part? use events, not timers.

Comment: its only a 5 second video :p if they want to see it again they can refresh

Comment: wait there is a problem. how do i make the video automatically play?

Comment: but the video is not from youtube. its directly from my server

Comment: <video src="videofile.ogg" autoplay >

Comment: this has been very helpful. thanks a lot brian!

Comment: wait where does that go : <frame width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/i_mKY2CQ9Kk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: sorry to sound like a noob, but would that plainly look like:

Comment: <video src="videofile.ogg" autoplay >

Comment: I updated the answer to use events, it will hide the overlay as soon as the video has ended. I also updated the example link.

Comment: If you prefer the original code: http://jsfiddle.net/pbzmjkoq/2/

Comment: will this code make the video disappear with the overlay?