# How to make video disappear after end in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

How do I make a video on an overlay all disappear after it has finished playing?
Is this javascript?

Here is the code I have so far:

[HTML / CSS Video end event issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274410/html-css-video-end-event-issue/25274611#25274611)

Comment: yes I understand... sort of... The current code does not make the overlay and video disappear after the video ends.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used them myself but there appears to be javascript events for video/audio, including `ended`.

`video.addEventListener('ended', foo);`

Where foo would be a function to hide the video.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yeah the current code plays the video and has a black overlay. I want both the overlay and video to disappear after the vieo is done

Comment: The answer by Brian to your previous post covers this doesn't it? So the video is selected, and the overlay is selected. Then an ended event is applied to the video which runs a function to make the overlay display "none", therefor making the overlay disappear. If the video is within the overlay, it too should disappear.

Comment: But thats the thing- it does not disappear. After the video ends it just stays like that. The overlay and video both do not disappear

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this jQuery [plugin](https://github.com/nirvanatikku/jQuery-TubePlayer-Plugin)

You can enable any action at the end of a video with something like this:

```
onPlayerEnded: function(){ // Do something here },
```

I found a post that could help you out [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624904/youtube-embeded-action-when-video-ends)